# NSOutlineView is constantly being updated even when app is idle

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

My macOS app is idle but the NSOutlineView is constantly being updated and taking 40% CPU. The only code of mine being called is the objectValueForTableColumn NSOutlineViewDataSource method, about 20 times a second.

Using Instruments it looks like the main runloop is constantly finding a Core Animation task to commit. (See 46-44 below).

```
  59 libdyld.dylib 3435.0  start
  58 FrogRadio 3435.0  main /Users/robertdodson/Pro/dev/FrogRadio/FrogRadio/FrogRadio/Main/main.m:13
  57 AppKit 3435.0  NSApplicationMain
  56 AppKit 3435.0  -[NSApplication run]
  55 AppKit 3426.0  -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]
  54 AppKit 3409.0  _DPSNextEvent
  53 HIToolbox 3408.0  _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter
  52 HIToolbox 3408.0  ReceiveNextEventCommon
  51 HIToolbox 3401.0  RunCurrentEventLoopInMode
  50 CoreFoundation 3393.0  CFRunLoopRunSpecific
  49 CoreFoundation 3386.0  __CFRunLoopRun
  48 CoreFoundation 3192.0  __CFRunLoopDoObservers
  47 CoreFoundation 3185.0  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
  46 AppKit 3158.0  __65+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayRefresh]_block_invoke
  45 QuartzCore 3117.0  CA::Transaction::commit()
  44 QuartzCore 2957.0  CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase)
  43 AppKit 2957.0  __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke
  42 AppKit 2948.0  ___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke.5902
  41 AppKit 2936.0  -[NSWindow displayIfNeeded]
  40 AppKit 2935.0  -[NSView displayIfNeeded]
  39 AppKit 2874.0  -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:]
  38 AppKit 2872.0  -[NSView _oldDisplayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:]
  37 AppKit 2816.0  -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:]
...
```

I have no Core Animation code in my app. I have refactored recently, and this is a new problem, but I can not see what I have done to cause it.

Any ideas here?

Thanks,
Rob

Update: adding full stack trace at objectValueForTableColumn call:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
* frame #0: 0x000000010001a3db FrogRadio`-[FRGTree outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:](self=0x0000600000002b10, _cmd="outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:", outlineView=0x0000000101c04130, tableColumn=0x000060c000082300, item=0x00006000000e7600) at FRGTree.m:101
frame #1: 0x00007fff2cd52756 AppKit`-[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 471
frame #2: 0x00007fff2cdd60af AppKit`-[NSOutlineView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 51
frame #3: 0x00007fff2cd523e7 AppKit`-[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 50
frame #4: 0x00007fff2cdd601f AppKit`-[NSOutlineView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 92
frame #5: 0x00007fff2cd520f2 AppKit`-[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 2186
frame #6: 0x00007fff2cd51568 AppKit`-[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 527
frame #7: 0x00007fff2cdd0ec2 AppKit`-[NSOutlineView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 112
frame #8: 0x00007fff2cc6fced AppKit`-[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1522
frame #9: 0x00007fff2d3bac21 AppKit`_NSViewDrawRect + 83
frame #10: 0x00007fff2cc53b38 AppKit`-[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 1819
frame #11: 0x00007fff2cc9bf62 AppKit`-[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1735
frame #12: 0x00007fff2cc9c42f AppKit`-[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2964
frame #13: 0x00007fff2cc51a52 AppKit`-[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 938
frame #14: 0x00007fff2cc522c1 AppKit`-[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 3097
frame #15: 0x00007fff2cc522c1 AppKit`-[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 3097
frame #16: 0x00007fff2cc522c1 AppKit`-[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 3097
frame #17: 0x00007fff2cc511db AppKit`-[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 327
frame #18: 0x00007fff2d3bc1d8 AppKit`-[NSView _oldDisplayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2051
frame #19: 0x00007fff2cc50261 AppKit`-[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 253
frame #20: 0x00007fff2cc4c4b8 AppKit`-[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1581
frame #21: 0x00007fff2cc4be56 AppKit`-[NSWindow displayIfNeeded] + 321
frame #22: 0x00007fff2d3ec2d9 AppKit`___NSWindowGetDisplayCycleObserver_block_invoke.5902 + 308
frame #23: 0x00007fff2cc4b962 AppKit`__37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke + 695
frame #24: 0x00007fff3a65878f QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::run_commit_handlers(CATransactionPhase) + 49
frame #25: 0x00007fff3a657301 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 171
frame #26: 0x00007fff2d403658 AppKit`__65+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayRefresh]_block_invoke + 283
frame #27: 0x00007fff2f548127 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
frame #28: 0x00007fff2f54804f CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 527
frame #29: 0x00007fff2f52a6a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1240
frame #30: 0x00007fff2f529f43 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 483
frame #31: 0x00007fff2e841e26 HIToolbox`RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
frame #32: 0x00007fff2e841b96 HIToolbox`ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
frame #33: 0x00007fff2e841914 HIToolbox`_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
frame #34: 0x00007fff2cb0cf5f AppKit`_DPSNextEvent + 2085
frame #35: 0x00007fff2d2a2b4c AppKit`-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
frame #36: 0x00007fff2cb01d6d AppKit`-[NSApplication run] + 764
frame #37: 0x00007fff2cad0f1a AppKit`NSApplicationMain + 804
frame #38: 0x00000001000456e2 FrogRadio`main(argc=3, argv=0x00007ffeefbff340) at main.m:13
frame #39: 0x00007fff56e41115 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Update 2: My NSOutlineViewDataSource code:

```
- (NSInteger) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView     numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item
{
     return (item == nil) ? 1 : ((FRGTreeNode*)item).children.count;
}

- (BOOL) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item
{
    return [((FRGTreeNode*)item) isExpandable];
}

- (id) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView child:(NSInteger)index ofItem:(id)item
{
    return (!item) ? _rootNode : ((FRGTreeNode*)item).children[index];
}

- (id) outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item
{
    NSLog(@"tree: %@",((FRGTreeNode*)item).nodename);
    return ((FRGTreeNode*)item).nodename;
}
```

Some notes: The NSLog method is getting call many times a second. Also, the outlineView works fine even though this is happening.

Comment: Core Animation drives all visual updates, regardless of whether you use it explicitly. Are you using Cocoa bindings?

Comment: If something is calling `objectValueForTableColumn:` unexpectedly, then you should post that stack trace.

Comment: I am not using Cocoa Bindings. The stack trace is: 
    [FRGTree outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:]
    [NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] ()
    NSApplicationMain ()

Comment: You need to edit the stack trace into your question, and you need to make sure Xcode isn't hiding any frames of the stack trace. The easiest way to get the full stack trace is by typing `bt` into the debugger console.

Comment: Thanks for the bt tip. I added the full stack trace above.

Comment: Something is marking the view as needing display. Show your `-[FRGTree outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem:]` method implementation. Also, look in the Instruments profile data at stacks other than the heaviest to see if there are any other calls into your code that keep happening.

Comment: I added my `NSOutlineViewDataSource` code above. Looking now at other threads. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe try temporarily making the outline view a custom subclass of `NSOutlineView`, overriding `setNeedsDisplay:` in the subclass with a method that just calls `super`'s implementation. Run the project, and once the repeated refreshing starts, put a breakpoint on that subclass method. Then maybe you can find out what's marking it as needing display.

Comment: Doh! Thanks to Charles idea I found the error. I was calling `setNeedsDisplay` in the `OutlineViewDelegate` for each cell in order have updated highlighting be correct. I will make this code smarter. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I was calling setNeedsDisplay in the `outlineView dataCellForTableColumn` for each cell in order have updated highlighting be correct, which is a bad idea. I will make this code smarter.